# How to grab filepath from ansibles find module

Tags: ansible, find, devops

I'm using Ansible for some IAC(infra as code) tasks.
I have a playbook where I'm using the find module recursively to search for readable files.

Here is an example of it:

```
- name: Application logs with read access
  become: true
  find:
    paths: /
    file_type: file
    recurse: yes
    patterns:
      - '*.log'
      - '*.config'
  register: rapplogs
- set_fact: read_app_logs={{rapplogs.matched}}
- debug: var=read_app_logs

- set_fact: read_log_list={{rapplogs.files}}
- debug: var=read_log_list
  run_once: True
  failed_when: read_app_logs >= 1
  ignore_errors: True
```

The output of it is like this:

```
TASK [infra_pt : set_fact] ******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.47.135]

TASK [infra_pt : debug] *********************************************************************
ok: [192.168.47.135] => {
    "read_app_logs": "72"
}

TASK [infra_pt : set_fact] ******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.47.135]

TASK [infra_pt : debug] *********************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.47.135]: FAILED! => {
    "failed_when_result": true, 
    "read_log_list": {
        "changed": false, 
        "examined": 210060, 
        "failed": false, 
        "files": [
            {
                "atime": 1558446815.3474104, 
                "ctime": 1558446815.3474104, 
                "dev": 64768, 
                "gid": 0, 
                "gr_name": "root", 
                "inode": 2065610, 
                "isblk": false, 
                "ischr": false, 
                "isdir": false, 
                "isfifo": false, 
                "isgid": false, 
                "islnk": false, 
                "isreg": true, 
                "issock": false, 
                "isuid": false, 
                "mode": "0644", 
                "mtime": 1558446815.3474104, 
                "nlink": 1, 
                "path": "/test2.log", 
                "pw_name": "root", 
                "rgrp": true, 
                "roth": true, 
                "rusr": true, 
                "size": 0, 
                "uid": 0, 
                "wgrp": false, 
                "woth": false, 
                "wusr": true, 
                "xgrp": false, 
                "xoth": false, 
                "xusr": false
            },
```

From the output list I actually want to access only the "mode" and "path" objects, how this can be done? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter)

```
- set_fact:
    read_app_logs: "{{ rapplogs.files|json_query('[].{path: path, mode: mode}') }}"
```

(not tested)

Comment: This looks like what I was looking for , easily readable output, you just need to install one dependency (jmespath) and you are ready to go. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can just iterate over the list of matched files and refer to whichever keys are of interest:

```
- debug:
    msg: "mode of {{ item.path }} is {{ item.mode }}"
  loop: "{{ read_log_list.files }}"
```

Which, given your example output, would produce something like this:

```
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'islnk': False, u'uid': 0, u'rgrp': True, u'xoth': False, u'rusr': True, u'woth': False, u'nlink': 1, u'issock': False, u'mtime': 1558446815.3474104, u'gr_name': u'root', u'path': u'/test2.log', u'xusr': False, u'atime': 1558446815.3474104, u'inode': 2065610, u'isgid': False, u'size': 0, u'isdir': False, u'wgrp': False, u'ctime': 1558446815.3474104, u'isblk': False, u'xgrp': False, u'isuid': False, u'dev': 64768, u'roth': True, u'isreg': True, u'isfifo': False, u'mode': u'0644', u'pw_name': u'root', u'gid': 0, u'ischr': False, u'wusr': True}) => {
    "msg": "mode of /test2.log is 0644"
}
```